# What is the meaning of D-BFDE?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

Google already helped with giving BFDE's meaning as *Board of Forensic Document Examiners*. But, I am reading a CV in which it reads D-BFDE. What does this stand for?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about a context-specific abbreviation unknown to almost all native speakers, not ***learning English***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it means "Diplomate of the (American) Board of Forensic Document Examiners" (possibly also others if such exist, I only found a reference to the title on ABFDE's page). So, basically, a certified expert.